# Creating a table using pure JavaScript (DOM) and given array of objects?

Tags: javascript

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAW28.png)

I have to create this table using JavaScript.

**What I have been Given:**

```
var users = [
{
    first_name: 'Kaitlin',
    last_name: 'Burns',
    age: 23,
    email: 'kburns99753@usermail.com'
},
{
    first_name: 'Joshua',
    last_name: 'Feir',
    age: 31,
    email: 'josh319726@usermail.com'
},
{
    first_name: 'Stephen',
    last_name: 'Shaw',
    age: 28,
    email: 'steve.shaw47628@usermail.com'
},
{
    first_name: 'Timothy',
    last_name: 'McAlpine',
    age: 37,
    email: 'Timbo72469@usermail.com'
},
{
    first_name: 'Sarah',
    last_name: 'Connor',
    age: 19,
    email: 'SarahC6320@usermail.com'
}
];
```

**What i have tried:**

```
var tabl = document.getElementById('tbl');
var newTbl = document.createElement('table');
var tHead = document.createElement('thead');
var tBody = document.createElement('tbody');

tabl.appendChild(newTbl);
newTbl.setAttribute('border', '1px solid');
newTbl.appendChild(tHead);

var tRow = document.createElement('tr');
var tCol = document.createElement('td');

tHead.appendChild(tRow);

console.log(newTbl);

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
{
 var tCol = document.createElement('td');
 tCol.innerHTML += users[i].first_name;
 tCol.innerHTML += users[i].last_name;
 tCol.innerHTML += users[i].age;
 tCol.innerHTML += users[i].email;
 tRow.appendChild(tCol);
}
```

My goal is to create a table using pure javascript. I had tried many ways although this way gives me a table that prints all of the values but puts them all into one row.

I need this table to look like the one provided above as it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're only creating one TD (table data cell) for each user, and you're putting all the data for a user into the one cell. If you want the different data pieces in different cells, you need to create a separate TD for each of them, and only fill each TD with one piece of data. (Then, of course, append all the cells to the same row.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create table inside table, you can use exising one.
You were creating columns inside table row instead of creating new rows and appending new columns to it.

Heres working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eubvrdxj/)

```
var tabl = document.getElementById('tbl');
var tHead = document.createElement('thead');
var tBody = document.createElement('tbody');

tabl.setAttribute('border', '1px solid');
tabl.appendChild(tHead);
tabl.appendChild(tBody);

var fieldTitles = ["First name", "Last name", "Age", "Email"]

var tHeadRow = document.createElement('tr');
tHead.appendChild(tHeadRow);

fieldTitles.forEach(function (field) {
     var tCol = document.createElement('td');
     tCol.innerHTML = field;
     tHeadRow.appendChild(tCol);
   })

var fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'email'];

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var tRow = document.createElement('tr');
  tabl.appendChild(tRow);

  fields.forEach(function (field) {
    var tCol = document.createElement('td');
    tCol.innerHTML = users[i][field];
    tRow.appendChild(tCol);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will dynamically create head based on data etc.

```js
const buildHead = (data) => {
  let tHead = document.createElement('thead');
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let sample = data[0];
  for(let prop in sample) {
    let th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerText = prop.replace('_', ' ');
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }  
  tHead.appendChild(tr);
  return tHead;
};

const buildBody = (data) => { 
  let tBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  data.forEach(d => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.values(d).forEach(val => {
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerText = val;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    tBody.appendChild(tr);
  });
  return tBody;
};

const buildTable = (data) => {
  let table = document.querySelector('table');
  table.appendChild(buildHead(data));
  table.appendChild(buildBody(data));  
};

var users = [{
    first_name: 'Kaitlin',
    last_name: 'Burns',
    age: 23,
    email: 'kburns99753@usermail.com'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Joshua',
    last_name: 'Feir',
    age: 31,
    email: 'josh319726@usermail.com'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Stephen',
    last_name: 'Shaw',
    age: 28,
    email: 'steve.shaw47628@usermail.com'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Timothy',
    last_name: 'McAlpine',
    age: 37,
    email: 'Timbo72469@usermail.com'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Sarah',
    last_name: 'Connor',
    age: 19,
    email: 'SarahC6320@usermail.com'
  }
];

buildTable(users);
```

```css
th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```